# When one button radio is check, show dateTypefrom, if not take value from TextType

Tags: symfony4, dql

I want to make an advanced search bar, for the moment i can choose (multiple choice are not allowed) in an array of category and use the repository corresponding, (using switch in my controller) But one of my category contain date and i want to show the DateType form only while the radio button of this category is selected and when the TextType is empty, only search by Date and if it's not, search first by text entry, then by date. I know that i need to use Javascript to do that, but i never use javascript in my life and i have to present my project in 2 days. Can you help me with that please?

My AdvancedSearchType.php :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

    $builder
        ->add('recherche', TextType::class)
        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class,[
            'label' => 'Choix de recherche',
            'choices' => [
                'Formateur' => 'formateur',
                'Session' => 'session',
                'Module' => 'module',
                'Stagiaire' => 'stagiaire',
                'Catégorie' => 'categorie',
            ],

         'multiple' => false,
         'expanded' => true
    ])

        ->add('begindate',DateType::class, [
        'label' => 'Date de Debut'
        ])
        ->add('enddate', DateType::class, [
        'label' => 'Date de Fin'
        ])
        ->add('Valider', SubmitType::class);

}
```

My SearchController.php :

```
/**
 * @Route("/search", name="search")
 */
public function search(Request $request, ObjectManager $em){

    $results = null;
    $form = $this->createForm(AdvencedSearchType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){  
        $query = $form->get('recherche')->getData();
        $type = $form->get('type')->getData();

        switch($type){
            case 'categorie':
                $repo = $em->getRepository(Categorie::class);
                break;
            case 'formateur':
                $repo = $em->getRepository(Formateur::class);
                break;
            case 'session':
                $repo = $em->getRepository(Session::class);
                break;
                case 'module':
                $repo = $em->getRepository(Module::class);
                break;                
            case 'stagiaire':
                $repo = $em->getRepository(Stagiaire::class);
                break;
                $results = $repo->search($query);
            default:
                return $this->redirectToRoute("search");


                break;
        }
        $results = $repo->search($query);
    }

    return $this->render('search/result.html.twig', [
        'search_form' => $form->createView(),
        'results' => $results

    ]); 

}
```

My SessionRepository (the one with the date) :

```
public function search($search){

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->orWhere('s.intitule LIKE :q')
    ->orWhere('s.dateDebut LIKE :q')
    ->orWhere('s.dateFin LIKE :q')
    ->orWhere('s.placeTotale LIKE :q')
    ->orWhere('s.dateDebut LIKE :q')
    ->orWhere('s.dateFin LIKE :q')


    ->setParameter('q', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;

}
```